# Don't manage to return on different lines objects from an array using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have a question regarding "map" with an array and objects.

I try to display on each row of the table, the name and first name of a user.

I think there is something that I misunderstood with map because I display the name of both users on the same line.

Do I have to go through a "for of" of the users array to generate one row per user?

```
 function DisplayUsersTable() {
        let users = [
            { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Connor" },
            { id: 2, firstName: "Geralt", lastName: "Rivia" }
        ]
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> firstName </th>
                        <th> lastName</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {users.map((user, index) =>(<td key={index}>{user.lastName}</td>))}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
```

Display:

```
   firstName    lastName
    Connor  Rivia
```

Thank you!

Comment: "*Do I have to go through a "for of" of the users array to generate one row per user?*" you don't *have to* - you can just use `map` for that as well. The problem is that you're generating one `<td>` per user with your current code. You seem to want one `<tr>` for each instead.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, everything is OK. I had misunderstood how map works! Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually misunderstood what map does and what your HTML does. so your map iterates through an array you give it and display each element of an array in the way you want to so the use of `map` is to iterate through the array so that you can have access to the single element of the array. HTML actually lets you manage how you want to print out your data. so the problem is not with your map it is with your HTML `<td>`.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the iteration part of "map". I just modified the html and it works fine. I also did two or three other tests and I think I understood how it works! Thank you very much for your explanation :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Now it works:

```
function ShowUserTable() {
        let users = [
            { firstName: "John", lastName: "Connor" },
            { firstName: "Geralt", lastName: "Rivia" },
            { firstName: "Nathan", lastName: "Drake" }
        ]
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> firstName </th>
                        <th> lastName</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
    
                        {users.map((user, index) =>(
                             <tr key={index}>
                                 <td>{user.firstName} </td>
                                 <td>{user.lastName} </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
    
    
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
```